# why not say 'to do'?

Tags: infinitives

I have an advanced student who said that she feels that something I wrote needs a ‘to’ immediately before the word ‘do’. I told her that I don’t know a grammar based explanation, but that I’d find one.

This is the sentence:

> This is an indirect way of suggesting that someone not do that.

She feels it ought to say 'not to do that'.

I read the answers to '“Why not do it” vs “why not to do it”'. But it seems to me mine isn't answered in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your advanced student is wrong.

> This is an indirect way of suggesting that someone not do that

Above, the subject of the second *do* in the *that* clause is *someone*.

> This is an indirect way of suggesting that someone not to do that

Above, what your student said changes *do* into an infinitive.  This means it takes over a noun function, and changes *do* from verb to noun.

After that change, the phrase after *that* is missing a verb.  For this to work, the sentence needs a verb added, like:

> This is an indirect way of suggesting that someone is not to do that

Answer (score 0):

*Suggest* (like *command* and *require*) may take a "that" clause where the verb is in the base form, eg:

> I suggest that he do this.

(Some people - more in British than American English, I think - use the present: *I suggest that he does this*. Historically what I've called the base form is a present subjunctive, but since the present subjunctive is indistinguishable from the base form for *every verb in the language*, I find it an unnecessary complication to give it a special name).

*Command* and *require* can also take an to-infinitive clause:

> They commanded him to do that.

as an alternative to the that clause

> They commanded that he do that.

but this option is not usual for *suggest*. There is no particular reason why not: it just happens to be a fact about these verbs in current English.